# Derivation of the prolongation formula for finding symmetries of diff equations from Olver

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I am having a problem with the derivation of the prolongation formula from PJ Olver's text :"Applications of Lie groups to differential equations" Page 105,106.

Considering a differential equation with independent variable(x) and one dependent variable(u).

(x,u) $\subset$ $X \times U$

The first jet space $M^{(1)}$ has the coordinates (x,$u^1$) = (x,u,$u_j$).

Suppose u = f(x) is any function with $u_j = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} $

First prolongation of a group action on M is given as:
$pr^{1} g_\epsilon . (x,u^{(1)}) = (\tilde{x},\tilde{u}^{(1)})$

The dependent variable is unchanged here so the following:

$\tilde{u} = \tilde{f}_\epsilon(\tilde{x}) = f[\Xi^{-1}_\epsilon(\tilde{x})] = f[\Xi_{-\epsilon} (\tilde{x})] $

Here I don't understand how $\tilde{f}$ has transformed to f.

Now with some further calculations, following expression arises involving a pull back where I don't understand how an interchange in the order of differentiation has been done.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde{x}^j} [\frac{d\Xi^k_{-\epsilon}}{d\epsilon} ] (\Xi_{\epsilon}(x)) |_{\epsilon = 0} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} [\frac{d\Xi^k_{\epsilon}}{d\epsilon} ] |_{\epsilon = 0} = - \frac{\partial \xi^k}{\partial x^j}(x)$

Please anybody help, if any further details are needed I will add in.

Comment: As Olver remarks, that formula for $\tilde{u}$ is an application of the general rule for transforming functions given in 2.14. There he considers the possibility that both the dependent and independent variables transform under the symmetry group. That said, an answer here explaining the how and why of 2.14 in Olver would make an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also find Olver's proof confusing, but the prolongation formula is actually quite simple.

Let $x^i$ be independent variables and $u^{\alpha}$ be dependent variables. Then we have the jet bundle whose coordinates are $x^i,u_J^{\alpha}$. We want to compute the symmetries of the jet bundle which preserve the jets of graphs $u^{\alpha} = f(x^i)$. The 1-forms
$$ \theta_J^{\alpha} = d u_J^{\alpha} - u_{Ji}^{\alpha} dx^i$$
vanish on these jets, so if
$$ V = f^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \phi^{\alpha}_j \frac{\partial}{\partial u^{\alpha}_J}$$
is an infinitesimal symmetry, then the 1-form $\mathcal{L}_V \theta_J^{\alpha}$ must also vanish on jets of graphs. If we evaluate this Lie derivative, it follows that
$$ \phi_{Ji}^{\alpha} = 
\frac{\partial \phi^{\alpha}_J}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial \phi^{\alpha}_J}{\partial u_K^{\beta}} u_{Ki}^{\beta} - u_{Jj}^{\alpha} \left( \frac{\partial f^j}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial f^j}{\partial u_K^{\beta}} u_{Ki}^{\beta} \right)$$
Here I am making heavy use of the Einstein summation convention. This is exactly the prolongation formula which Olver is proving.